# Python3 Wolframalpha Giving Error: urllib.error.URLError <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>

Tags: python-3.x, urllib, errno, urlopen, wolframalpha

Alright so a few days ago I wrote this code and it worked fine.

```
import wolframalpha

app_id = "MY-APP-ID-HERE"

client = wolframalpha.Client(app_id)

my_input = input("Question: ")

res = client.query(my_input)
```

Then today it just stopped working, randomly and started throwing this error.

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 101] Network is unreachable>
```

Why is this happening I didn't even modify the code or anything and my Wifi is up and my other devices are working on it fine.

i'm on a Raspberry Pi, running Raspbian Pixel. Is wolfram alpha down or patching a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Network is unreachable" - urllib is unable to physically connect to the service.

Typically this is because some hardware link between you and the remote site is down.

To debug this, a good start is to simply try and open the page in your browser (or `ping` the server).  It's likely you will receive the same error.  If that doesn't work, try a different site - narrow the problem down to what you can connect to, and what is not reachable.  Can you even connect to something else in your house?

It could be a whole lot of local issues, like cable unplugged, modem offline, duplicated IP addresses, etc. etc.  But my guess is that it's *a localised problem* to you.  Yes it's possible that your ISP is down, or your country's link was cut, but that's far less likely.

Comment: thanks yeah that helped it's working now. Hopefully it will stay that way